# What is Parse/parsing?

Tags: java, parsing

In Java, What exactly is Parsing?  Why are they used?

For example: `Integer.parseInt(...)`, and parsing a string?

Answer (score 62):

You could say that *parsing a string of characters* is *analyzing this string to find tokens, or items and then create a structure from the result*.

In your example, calling `Integer.parseInt` on a string is *parsing this string to find an integer*.

So, if you have:

```
String someString = "123";
```

And then you invoke:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt( someString );
```

You're telling java to analyze the `"123"` string and find an integer there.

**Other example:**

One of the actions the java compiler does, when it compiles your source code is to "parse" your .java file and create tokens that match the java grammar.

When you fail to write the source code properly ( for instance forget to add a `;` at the end of a statement ), it is the parser who identifies the error.

Here's more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse

Comment: I wonder, why the top rated answer is not at the top.

Comment: @Faizan What do you mean? Are you sure you [sort answers by votes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787735/what-is-parse-parsing?answertab=votes#tab-top)?

Comment: Does everyone agree that this is the correct definition?

Answer (score 37):

Parsing is to read the value of one object to convert it to another type. For example you may have a string with a value of "10". Internally that string contains the Unicode characters '1' and '0' not the actual number 10. The method Integer.parseInt takes that string value and returns a real number.

```
String tenString = "10"

//This won't work since you can't add an integer and a string
Integer result = 20 + tenString;

//This will set result to 30
Integer result = 20 + Integer.parseInt(tenString);
```

Comment: "Parsing is to read the value of one object to convert it to another type". Well that's only part of what parsing is. Parsing is the process of taking data (text) and determining its meaning based on a set of rules.

Comment: +1 for implementation. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788796/what-is-parsing

Answer (score 9):

From [dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/parse):

> Computers. to analyze (a string of
>   characters) in order to associate
>   groups of characters with the
>   syntactic units of the underlying
>   grammar.

The context of the definition is the translation of program text or a language in the general sense into its component parts with respect to a defined grammar -- turning program text into code.  In the context of a particular language keyword, though, it generally means to convert the string value of a fundamental data type into an internal representation of that data type. For example, the string "10" becomes the number (integer) 10.

Answer (score 7):

Parsing can be considered as a synonym of "Breaking down into small pieces" and then analysing what is there or using it in a modified way. In Java, Strings are parsed into Decimal, Octal, Binary, Hexadecimal, etc. It is done if your application is taking input from the user in the form of string but somewhere in your application you want to use that input in the form of an integer or of double type. It is not same as type casting. For type casting the types used should be compatible in order to caste but nothing such in parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing is the division of text in to a set of parts or tokens.

Comment: -1 Sorry, this is really hard to understand and doesn't add anything not covered by the other answers.  Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: +1. While the structure could be better, (submitting an edit,) your answer is precise and refreshingly brief.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing is just process of analyse the string of character and find the tokens from that string and parser is a component of interpreter and compiler.It uses lexical analysis and then
syntactic analysis.It parse it and then compile this code after this whole process of compilation.

Comment: How does your answer provide anything that the other answers didn't?

Answer (score 0):

**Parsing** means we are analyzing an object specifically. For example, when we enter some keywords in a search engine, they parse the keywords and give back results by searching for each word. So it is basically taking a string from the file and processing it to extract the information we want.

Example of parsing using `indexOf` to calculate the position of a string in another string:

```
String s="What a Beautiful day!";

int i=s.indexOf("day");//value of i would be 17
int j=s.indexOf("be");//value of j would be -1
int k=s.indexOf("ea");//value of k would be 8
```

`paresInt` essentially converts a `String` to a `Integer`.

```
String s="9876543";
int a=new Integer(s);//uses constructor
System.out.println("Constructor method: " + a);
a=Integer.parseInt(s);//uses parseInt() method
System.out.println("parseInt() method: " + a);
```

Output:

> ```
> Constructor method: 9876543
>
> parseInt() method: 9876543
> ```

Comment: But whats the "parse" in it??