# What is code parsing?

Tags: javascript, html, parsing

I have been creating and working on different websites. Many a times a get a problem that the `code needs to be parsed`(One good example is when I wanted to display Ads between the posts. I had to parse the code script to work.) I am really confused about what actually parsing is. I had googled for it but did not found any satisfactory results to clear out the concept. I would be very thankful if anyone could explain me what parsing actually is and why is it necessary in some cases?

I have read [What is parsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788796/what-is-parsing) but I did not helped me to clear out the concept. Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? John's answer brings it to the point IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In very simple terms parsing is transforming one thing to another with equal meaning.
For example:

- (Dec) 66
- (Hex) 42
- (Oct) 102
- (Html) &#66

Those all state the same letter B.

So if id parse the letter B to html I'd get &#66.

What you are doing with parsing your code is practically the same.

Comment: Why do we need to parse if its the same?

Comment: Well for example a function only accepts a double as parameter. You only have a integer value. In this case you can parse your integer to a double so it can be passed on as a parameter. Or for example you get a json string and need an array. In this case you can parse the json string to an array.