# How to print a string with an int

Tags: java, string, int

I am trying to get this code to run and basically solve an equation. So, I asked the user to write an equation. It looked like this:

```
System.out.println("Write an equation and I will solve for x.");
int answer = in.nextLine();
```

But I can't get the user to write a string and an int. Do I need to say String answer or int answer?

Comment: `String answer` if you want them to input an equation.  You will then need to parse it, determining its operators and operands, and solve for x.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with parse, could you show me an example, please?

Comment: here is an example  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787735/what-is-parse-parsing

Comment: @Nikki can you please post example of equation.

Comment: To test out  the equation I am using 6x = 3.

Comment: On another note, Nikki, there is no solution to `6x = 3` if you restrict `x` to being an `int`.  You may want to use `float` or `double` for the solution to an equation like this one.

Comment: Are you writing logic for solving equations or are you asking how to solve the equation, because the user is going to enter a equation that you will read it and pass it to some algorithm which will calculate the result (in your case value of x) and return it to you.

Answer (score 0):

An int is used when you want the user to enter a number, but here you're looking for a combination of numbers and other characters, so you will need to use a string. When you have the equation stored in a string, you can use other methods to split up the equation into something solvable, then set int answer to whatever the answer comes out to be.

Comment: Just use methods to split up the equation into ints?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking without an example equation. Are you dealing with just one variable?

Answer (score 0):

On a simpler side, String will be required input from the user, User will enter the equation.

Then comes the complex part of solving/computing the equation.

1.) create your own parser to pass `operands/operator`.

2.) Provide a equation with values to some `API`, you can make use of [MVEL](http://mvel.codehaus.org/) or [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little program that demonstrates one way to get the equation and divide into numeric / non-numeric values provided the equation input is space delimited. You can then determine what the non-numeric values are and proceed from there.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SolveX{

    public static void main(String[] a){

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Write an equation and I will solve for x.");
        String input = "";

        while( in.hasNext() ){
            input = in.next();
            try{  
                double d = Double.parseDouble(input);
                System.out.println("Double found at: " + input);
                //  Do what you need to with the numeric value
            }  
            catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
                System.out.println("No double found at: " + input);
              //    Do what you need to with the non numeric value 
            }
        }
    }//end main
}//end SolveX class
```