# Difference between parse ,stream, observable ,de/serlialization

Tags: java, android, rest, io, retrofit

I have read that
Serialization = encoding.
Deserialization = decoding = parsing
Is that true ?
And how streaming is related to them
Is retrofit change stream into observable ?

Comment: Parsing/Parse - Converting object from one type to another type https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787735/what-is-parse-parsing#:~:text=Parsing%20is%20to%20read%20the,and%20returns%20a%20real%20number.

Comment: Stream- is used to process collections of object
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stream-in-java/#:~:text=A%20stream%20is%20a%20sequence,Arrays%20or%20I%2FO%20channels.

Comment: Serialization - Save state of object.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/serialization-in-java/